# Application that can detect movement speed of a car

Tags: android

I am planning to develop an android mobile application for detecting speed of a user while s/he is driving a car. the aim of my project is to tell the user if he exceed the max limit speed while he is driving his/her car to prevent from violation speed limit. can you tell me please what kind of technology do I need to know to be able to make my app detect the speed of user car

Comment: All recent smartphones have a built-in GPS receiver. That's exactly what you need. (Doesn't work in tunnels though)

Comment: You shouldn't look on your phone while driving!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47097127/9977151 related

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570542/determining-the-speed-of-a-vehicle-using-gps-in-android maybe it can help